# LESS CSS - returning a variable conditionally

Tags: css, less

I use LESS CSS, and already use the 'return' functionality.

```
.get-theme-color(@theme) {
    @return: ~"@{mdc-theme-@{theme}}";
}
```

And use it to assign values this:

```
@var: .get-theme-color(primary)[];
```

However, I'm trying to return a value selectively using a mixin. I've tried various formats - this is what I'm currently trying to make work - with no success:

```
.get-property-box(@mask) when (length(@mask) >= 1) and (length(@mask) =< 4) {
    @mask-len: length(@mask);

    @val1: extract(@mask, 1);
    @value: ~"@{val1}";

    & when (@mask-len = 2) {
        @val2: extract(@mask, 2);
        @value: ~"@{val1} @{val2}";
    }
    & when (@mask-len = 3) {
        @val2: extract(@mask, 2);
        @val3: extract(@mask, 3);
        @value: ~"@{val1} @{val2} @{val3}";
    }
    & when (@mask-len = 4) {
        @val2: extract(@mask, 2);
        @val3: extract(@mask, 3);
        @val4: extract(@mask, 4);
        @value: ~"@{val1} @{val2} @{val3} @{val4}";
    }

    @return: @value;
}
```

Here's an alternative version:

```
.get-property-box(@mask) when (length(@mask) >= 1) and (length(@mask) =< 4) {
    @mask-len: length(@mask);

    @val1: extract(@mask, 1);
    @return: ~"@{val1}";

    & when (@mask-len = 2) {
        @val2: extract(@mask, 2);
        @return: ~"@{val1} @{val2}";
    }
    & when (@mask-len = 3) {
        @val2: extract(@mask, 2);
        @val3: extract(@mask, 3);
        @return: ~"@{val1} @{val2} @{val3}";
    }
    & when (@mask-len = 4) {
        @val2: extract(@mask, 2);
        @val3: extract(@mask, 3);
        @val4: extract(@mask, 4);
        @return: ~"@{val1} @{val2} @{val3} @{val4}";
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
.mdc-shape(round) {
    @mask: 4rem, 5rem;
    border-radius: .get-property-box(@mask)[];
}
```

The output is:

```
border-radius: 4rem;
```

I know that the guards are working correctly (the relevant section is reached), but the return value isn't updated.

Anyone got advice as to how I can make this work?

Comment: Simply note that variables defined within `& when {}` blocks are not visible outside of it (just like they are not visible with regular rulesets like `body {}`). Thus simply can't (and should) not have any effect outside of the corresponding `{}` block (for more details see [this discussion](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2072#issuecomment-90918318)). It's not a problem to get them visible if you convert the conditionals into either of: a. set properties instead of variables. b. parametric mixins instead of `& when` (for examples see the linked thread) c. `if` function calls, but ...

Comment: Speaking of this particular `.get-property-box` implementation - considering that its essential function is only to convert a comma separated list to a space separated list, the idea of explicitly hardcoding each length(n) case looks strange. A loop would do this in [much more simple and compact](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/8d03bdb0b14a67c21ae5a16a72542063) fashion.